# BlackBerry 4.2 JDE for Eclipse

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have developed an app for Blackberry 5.0. Now I am trying to make the app available for 4.2 version onwards.

I have used Blackberry 1.1 plugin for eclipse 3.5, but I can't get the 4.2 JDE to show up in my Eclipse update list - using URL http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java

I manually downloaded the 4.2 component pack and installed it. I have created a new project and added 4.2 jar file to the User path that is in the installation directory.  There are two issues:

1) It does not seem to be working and also I can't get a cod file in the deliverables folder when I build the project.
2) The simulator that is provided with the jde doesnt seem to be working. I can't even launch the simulator. Should I download 4.2 simulators from BB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Blackberry Eclipse Plugin 1.1 works with 4.2 component pack. The previous version worked.
1.1 supports only jde 4.5 and higher.

Comment: can u plz tell me to work on BB 4.2 with any eclipse. I have code signing keys installed in the eclipse plugin 1.1. Will they work if i install any other version?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find the old plugin in the developer portal. But, you can always use the JDE. You can download from http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp I don't think that would affect your code signing keys